# Is it possible to do freelancing with 3dsmax?

Tags: 3dsmax

I am learning 3dsmax architecture for building models of houses. Is it possible to do freelancing with house modelling thing?  For various reasons I have to stay at home.

So I was wondering if I can earn some money by making some house models for someone.

I really don't know how this works but may be someone can give some ideas.

Would I need to go to construction or real estate companies and ask them if they want something like this?

Comment: What is "3dsmax architecture"?  I don't see it on their product page: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=16573920

Comment: Its not product but its course i did which only involves making house architecture not animation .

Comment: This is not the right community for this question.

Comment: I tried but couldn't find where i can ask animation related question. is there any SE for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two paths you can go down.

1) Prepare models beforehand and try to sell them.  A pretty popular website with a lot of art on it is TurboSquid.  http://support.turbosquid.com/entries/174743-publishing-products  This lets you work on what you know and at your own pace.

2) Join an art collective that does outsourcing and do work for hire.  I know some people who did this from home, but I can't think of the name of the company they went through.  This is generally more demanding and you'd be expected to do revisions and so forth. You'd be either paid on a per-piece or by schedule.

As I'm not an artist I can't really comment any further, but those are your basic options.